# Text disappears after UITextView zoom and rotation

Tags: ios, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I added a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` on `UITextView`. When I do a pinch or rotation, I change the transform property of my `UITextView` object. However, if I rotate it at some angle and zoom in to some scale, the text will suddenly disappear.

If I continue to rotate it, the text can reappear at some angle.

Is there any way to fix the disappearance?

Here's what I did with the gesture recognizer methods.

```
- (void)onPinchtextView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer {
CGFloat scale = pinchGestureRecognizer.scale;
if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    self.textView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.textView.transform, scale, scale);
    pinchGestureRecognizer.scale = 1.f;
}

- (void)onRotatetextView:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rotateGestureRecognizer {
    CGFloat rotation = rotateGestureRecognizer.rotation;
    if (rotateGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || rotateGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.textView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.textView.transform, rotation);
        [rotateGestureRecognizer setRotation:0];
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you add some of your code.

Comment: Great idea. @Kuldeep

Comment: @P.Tsin, i guess you want to achieve Rotation & Pinch to textView but the you facing an issue of text Disappear. right? I implemented this in swift and it's working fine.

Comment: Same here. Same code in Swift works fine. What scale and rotation are you having the problem at?